# Creating Indexed View which references a Non Indexed View and objects from multiple DB's

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following objects used in the following format in a create view statement.

```
dbo.objects1 A
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.object2 
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.object3 
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.object4
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.object5
```

The `objects1` is a table from `Database1` which has Indexes. The `objects2 through objects5`  are in another `database` and all these 4 objects are view with `No indexes`.

Now I am trying to create an indexed view with all the above five objects but SQL server is not allowing me.

First error is:

`Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.`

Second error is:

`Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.vw_Order' because name 'db2.dbo.object2' is invalid for schema binding.`

Now I googled these errors and I came to following assumptions:

1. Views cannot contain objects from multiple databases in a join query.
2. In order to create indexes on a view, all the objects in the view should have either indexes or should be schema binded (like Functions).

When I run the view like a query, Execution Plan is recommending me to create an index on columns from objects in db2. Please let me know if my assumptions are correct. If not, please let me know a way as to how I can create a view in this situation.

Answer (score 19):

As you have already done the research that all the objects(tables/View) in a definition of an indexed view must have `TWO PART` name i.e `[Schema].[Object]` it means all the objects will be in one database and you cannot create indexed view across multiple databases. Indexed views come with a lot of limitations, consider creating a stored procedure if possible

Other error that you are getting is you are missing `WITH SCHEMABINDING` option in your view's definition. It is a must requirement for creating an indexed view that you must use the WITH SCHEMABINDING option when creating indexed view i.e none of the underlying tables/objects schema can be changed until you drop this view.

Again I would suggest to look into stored procedures as it seems impossible in your case to create an Indexed View because of all the limitation that come with it.

Comment: I thought there might be some flexibility that SQL provided that I wasn't aware of. But with my more research your response, it seems that it is one of the limitation for Views. The reason I want to create an indexed view (and use that in a sproc) is because a sproc is not going to help much because the query takes over 1 hr to run and a sproc might just improve that run time by a couple of minutes.

Comment: one hour wow, well consider some schema modification then, move tables into one database(if possible). Or atleast get the required data in one or two tables in a database where most of your data is and try to denormalize the data a little bit.

Comment: Indexed views sound handy but I was told that they were just built to beat some TPC benchmark and in practice they are too limited to be of use. Have you tried optimising your existing query? If it takes an hour to run then it would take an hour to build the indexed view anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Add the owner to the view name and tables.
Like:

```
Create VIEW dbo.MyView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    SELECT * From dbo.Users
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create indexed view using two objects of different databases.